# Best practices for technical dependencies in API artifacts

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, maven, dependency-management

Use case: I'm currently working in a project consisting of several micro-services. For ease of use and in order to version the APIs properly each service provides a separate maven artifact for the API. However due to using Spring-Web, Jackson, et cetera there are some technical dependencies (Spring Web, Jackson, Reactor) in the APIs. Sooner or later that might cause issues with the dev teams of other micro-services using conflicting versions of these technical dependencies.

```
package random.price.api

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux

@RequestMapping(value = ["/v1/price"], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
interface PriceApi {

    @ApiOperation("Triggers a calculation")
    @ApiResponses(
        ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success/OK")
    )
    @PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<Any> calculate()

    @ApiOperation("Gets all prices for a product")
    @ApiResponses(
        ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success/OK"),
        ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "NotFound - Product with id unknown")
    )
    @GetMapping("/{productId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Flux<Prices>> getPrices(@PathVariable("productId") String productId)
```

Are there any best practices on how to avoid this without implementing separate API clients and providing some kind of SDK?

Comment: A standard way to handle such cases is Maven BOM (Bill of Material) POMs as explained in [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms)

Comment: Hi Tasos, 
thanks for pointing me that way. Probably I did not explain the issue well enough, but a BOM is not solving this, as I still need to have technical dependencies (as seen in the code example with having reactor/spring-web annotations imports there).